# Random card will generate only once

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a card game in which every time a button is clicked a playing card is reveal a random card however this only works once for the first click then nothing after that.I am quite new to coding especially javascript
and despite my best effort i cannot get the rest of the cards to generate. I sure its something simple .Any help would be fantastic.

https://github.com/kingnarwal/Tv_Card_Game.git

Comment: As opposed to adding a link to your code, can you please add a code sample inside the question itself?

Comment: Yes, as @Matthijs pointed out, (including code sample in the question itself) would be helpful for future visitors to this question as your source code is bound to change over time firstly, and secondly there is no guarantee that the link will even be active in the future.

Comment: Thankyou for taking the time to look at my first stack overflow question. I will make sure i i include a code sample with my next question.Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

You're only randomizing when the .js file loads, one time, not on click.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following Part to your .js File:

```
var elementid = "button"; //Your Button-ID here

var button = document.getElementById(elementid);
button.onclick = function(){


//Your Random-Card-Generator-Code here
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: A massive thankyou for taking the time to look at my question.It always felt that i should that be able to solve it and that the solution must be quite simple .Sometimes the most difficult part of writing code is to not let self doubt stop you.

Answer (score 0):

A couple issues: first you are using duplicate ids (`random_card_return`.) I changed them to be a class. IDs need to be unique. I had to then change your element selector to:

```
document.querySelector("#card" + clickCounter + " .random_card_return").innerHTML = (imageArray[random_number]);
```

See the full code below to see where I declare the `clickCounter` variable and where I increment it. This works since you have a unique id for each card (`#card1`, etc.) Only thing is I made the first card `#card0`.

Next, the `random_number` you are generating is outside the `addEventListener` callback function so it will always be the same number with each click. Moved it to inside the callback function so that it generates a new number every time.

The code could be further improved from what I've posted, for example you will encounter an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null` error once you've clicked through all the cards. This can be easily corrected but I'll leave it up to you.

**[JSFiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/damo_s/Lkve5qtr/)**

```js
var clickCounter = 0;

document.querySelector("#clickbtn").addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
  var el = document.querySelector(".flip-card:nth-child(1):not(.flipped), .flip-card.flipped + .flip-card:not(.flipped)");
  var random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1;
  console.log(el);
  el.classList.add("flipped");

document.querySelector("#card" + clickCounter + " .random_card_return").innerHTML = (imageArray[random_number]);

// Increment clickCounter
clickCounter++;

});



var imageArray = [("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/ideyyn00p/image01.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/qk6yq7q3d/image02.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/6e8252jtl/image03.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/4np13l2ah/image04.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/ad59nw8gp/image05.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/530awlo7t/image06.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/4ergdnpi1/image07.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/dntmnrye1/image08.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/4hbc0ht5l/image09.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/jrb77oont/image10.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/3ucfayw9l/image11.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/gn0jaw7vd/image12.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/tu47z0ont/image13.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/hgrds3yzd/image14.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/l1n9bc3ix/image15.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/l2x74r5cp/image16.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/5ipte7v89/image17.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/xy56rikm1/image18.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/yrmdxvg0p/image19.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/5hkgyjis9/image20.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/47mnjhp09/image21.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/6evhl5jo9/image22.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/r1k76h32x/image23.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/x51rqdtcp/image24.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/avnujtxw9/image25.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/makboga8p/image26.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/60u5ljzkp/image27.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/apf7duv2x/image28.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/4e9zxftuh/image29.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/ucdm3gzbt/image30.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/iojk8xa6x/image31.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/qvbk0i09l/image32.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/w9exlsfdl/image33.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/8kzfqiiu1/image34.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/uzh46qlll/image35.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/zb5pvqsih/image36.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/pf4mw3mqh/image37.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/w6v1yybq1/image38.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/xzxyn9wwp/image39.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/49fff91ax/image40.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/4ngreuleh/image41.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/7vl8rw7o9/image42.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/qp71ow5w9/image43.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/tkk4vr9w9/image44.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/9r8131wih/image45.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/8q7sdxfix/image46.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/o07nl4b15/image47.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/vu896iiu1/image48.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/7rrfbn26x/image49.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/src4gvt95/image50.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/ygsd16zfd/image51.png' width='154px' height='231px';>"),
  ("<img src='http://s20.postimg.org/jyv5t7849/image52.png' width='154px' height='231px';>")

];
```

```css
h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

.card-container {
  -webkit-perspective: 700;
  -ms-perspective: 700;
  perspective: 700;
}

.flip-card.flipped {
  -webkit-animation: card-flipper linear 0.5s;
  animation: card-flipper linear 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

@-webkit-keyframes card-flipper {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes card-flipper {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}

.back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front,
.back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 154px;
  height: 231px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 650px;
  left: 825px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 45px;
  background: lightblue;
}

#card0 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 308px;
}

#card1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 539px;
}

#card2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 770px;
}

#card3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 1004px;
}

#card4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 1235px;
}

#card5 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 1466px;
}

#card6 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 408px;
  left: 308px;
}

#card7 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 408px;
  left: 539px;
}

#card8 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 408px;
  left: 770px;
}

#card9 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 408px;
  left: 1004px;
}

#card10 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 408px;
  left: 1235px;
}

#card11 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 408px;
  left: 1466px;
}

#card0,
#card1,
#card2,
#card3,
#card4,
#card5,
#card6,
#card7,
#card8,
#card9,
#card10,
#card11 {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 160px;
  width: 154px;
  height: 231px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="flip-card" id="card0">
    <div class="front">
      <img src='http://s20.postimg.org/w3afa6l09/b2fv.png' width='154px' height='231px' ;>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div class="random_card_return"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flip-card" id="card1">
    <div class="front">
      <img src='http://s20.postimg.org/w3afa6l09/b2fv.png' width='154px' height='231px' ;>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div class="random_card_return"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flip-card" id="card2">
    <div class="front">
      <img src='http://s20.postimg.org/w3afa6l09/b2fv.png' width='154px' height='231px' ;>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div class="random_card_return"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flip-card" id="card3">
    <div class="front">
      <img src='http://s20.postimg.org/w3afa6l09/b2fv.png' width='154px' height='231px' ;>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div class="random_card_return"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flip-card" id="card4">
    <div class="front">
      <img src='http://s20.postimg.org/w3afa6l09/b2fv.png' width='154px' height='231px' ;>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div class="random_card_return"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flip-card" id="card5">
    <div class="front">
      <img src='http://s20.postimg.org/w3afa6l09/b2fv.png' width='154px' height='231px' ;>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div class="random_card_return"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flip-card" id="card6">
    <div class="front">
      <img src='http://s20.postimg.org/w3afa6l09/b2fv.png' width='154px' height='231px' ;>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div class="random_card_return"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flip-card" id="card7">
    <div class="front">
      <img src='http://s20.postimg.org/w3afa6l09/b2fv.png' width='154px' height='231px' ;>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div class="random_card_return"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flip-card" id="card8">
    <div class="front">
      <img src='http://s20.postimg.org/w3afa6l09/b2fv.png' width='154px' height='231px' ;>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div class="random_card_return"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flip-card" id="card9">
    <div class="front">
      <img src='http://s20.postimg.org/w3afa6l09/b2fv.png' width='154px' height='231px' ;>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div class="random_card_return"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flip-card" id="card10">
    <div class="front">
      <img src='http://s20.postimg.org/w3afa6l09/b2fv.png' width='154px' height='231px' ;>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div class="random_card_return"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flip-card" id="card11">
    <div class="front">
      <img src='http://s20.postimg.org/w3afa6l09/b2fv.png' width='154px' height='231px' ;>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div class="random_card_return"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<a href="#card" id="clickbtn">Click Me</a>
```

By the way, maybe you have a reason for it but you're loading jQuery in your HTML and not using it in your javascript.

Comment: The jquery link in my html as been there for so long i almost forgot about i guess i was at some point going to include some jquery I will give it the chop. A massive thankyou for taking the time to look at my question.